# display user input value after Submit in react with html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

display user input value upon submit

In this code i saw from other thread/post here in Stackoverflow,
'''''''


{submittedText && (

You just typed: {submittedText}

)}

'''''

---

These are all my codes attached above... How would I enter text in input field/text box for many times? and put alert related to the text inputted.
ex: Cat, dog, snake

The output below should be
Student's name: cat
(space)
STudent's name: dog etc

Thank you!

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

If it means that you want to see the values entered in the past as well as the values entered now, you can use a **string array**.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";

export default function App() {
  const [enteredText, setEnteredText] = useState("");
  const [submittedText, setSubmittedText] = useState([]);

  const textChangeHandler = (i) => {
    setEnteredText(i.target.value);
  };

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSubmittedText([...submittedText, enteredText]);
    setEnteredText("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Get user input</h1>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <input
        placeholder="type something"
        type="text"
        value={enteredText}
        onChange={textChangeHandler}
      />
      <button type="submit" >
        Submit
      </button>
      </form>
      {submittedText.map(el => <p>You just typed: {el}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: These are all my codes attached above(will attach in few minutes)... How would I input in input field/text box many times?
ex: Cat, dog, snake

The output below should be
Student's name: cat
STudent's name: dog etc

Code-----

Comment: {submittedText.map(el => <p>You just typed: {el}</p>)}

this Line above is not working (the one with .map),  it says "submittedText is not defined"

Comment: I can't give an exact answer because I don't know how well JSX works in react-native.

Comment: The code I wrote works fine in codesandbox. I checked again, and there seems to be no problem with the code.

Comment: I don't know if it's what you want, but I wrote it in react-native simply. Check it out and use it if you can.

[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-kirch-hdpd8f?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: thank you so much!!!! :) its now working and thanks also for the idea i got new ideas from Your code :)  thank you all the best! :D

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear ,maybe you are talking about execute code on field change
So this might help

```
const Somename = () => {

const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
  username: ''
});  

  const handleFieldChange = e => {
  setFormData({
    ...formData,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });
};

return (
  <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Form.Group className="mb-3">
      {hasLabel && <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>}
      <Form.Control
        placeholder={!hasLabel ? 'Name' : ''}
        value={formData.username}
        name="username"
        onChange={handleFieldChange}
        type="text"
      />
    </Form.Group>
 </Form>
  );
 };
```

Comment: Hi... Thankyou too for your help!  Take care!! :)))))